# Practical Image Sizes for App deployed to Android Devices - Background Image and Sprites

Tags: android

I've reviewed the Android official document on screen sizes like the reference below:
Now I am interested in publishing an application to marketplace and I want to know  1) What I need to support for acceptance 2)  What will provide me with good coverage for majority of devices.  I don't have time to make sprites and background images for every HW scenario so I r need to know what is common practice. Especially for sprites 32x32 and 64x64?  what about density?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Answer (score 1):

The bvest thing to do is create different sprites and add them to the res/ folders. such as ldp, mdpi and so forth.

Also you could work with Vector images this will also help. What ive done is tested out what size images work on HDPI devices and put seperate images for each.

This is the best approach. I guess this why google gives you this option.

Comment: What I am trying to determine is what is optimal for 80% of the devices out there.

Comment: Also what was the conclusion of your effort? did you end up favoring Vector images and for which category of devices?